# Android GCM not receiving notification when Service has been killed

Tags: android, service, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I know there is a lot of questions about this, but every time the issue where because they were "force-killing" their app through the App Manager.

This isn't my case.

I run a service, that should handle the GCM Notification.
When the service is running, everything works just fine !

**BUT**

If I launch another App really eager of RAM, let's say Something like a game, the Android will kill my service (in order to restart it later when RAM is no more an issue).

The thing is, If I start the said game, and send while the game is running (when I'm sure that the service has been killed by the device -- looking at running processes on Eclipse), it does not get any messages...
Until I stop the game, wait like 3-4 minutes (probably for the GC to come around) then, and only then (when the service is restarted) I get the GCM Notifications.

The entry point of the application makes me think that the service is restarted because RAM usage was low enough to start my service back, and not because GCM received a notification.

Is that a normal behavior of GCM notification system ?
Is their any way to get the service run as soon as I get a GCM notification ?

Here's what's in the manifest :

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.my.package.service.C2DMMessageReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

        <category android:name="com.my.package.service"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And Here's the entire class C2DMMessageReceiver :

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
            Log.d("C2DM", "#### GOT PUSH ####");
            Communication2.getInstance().reconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you starting your service as Foreground? (basic question)

Comment: No, I do not, I think this would be kinda annoying for the user.

Comment: Well… here's the thing. There's no workaround. Services are designed to live unless something more important needs the memory. Setting them as foreground (and having to add a notification) is a way to tell the user (and android) hey, this service must remain active for as much as you can. Truth is, your app SHOULD receive the GCM even if your app dies (not the same as Force Stop).

Comment: I suspect that if the memory is low (because of the game running) then there's nothing you can really do, the phone is doing something more important at that time given the resources it has.

Comment: I get that the service get killed sometime when the phone needs memory (even if it does take less than a MB), but like you said, if I send a push notification while the App is not running, it should receive it right away, doesn't it ?

Comment: The notification will be broadcasted and your broadcast receiver should "receive" the intent. But when memory is low, everything goes coo-coo in mobile :)

Comment: Yeah I guess Android are coo-coo's ;-) If so, that means it is a poorly designed OS...

Comment: After almost four years of Mobile dev (both Android and iOS), I can only say one thing: iOS is not magical either. Both have good and bad things.

Comment: No but at least iOS delivers notification in time ;-)

Comment: Try making an activity (instead of the service) to see if that is more responsive.

Comment: Activity or Service, the thing is, the onReceive doesn't get called, I don't get how more responsive it would be :-)

Comment: I dont understand what you are doing here, you say you have a service but you show a `BroadcastReceiver` (which isnt implemented correctly according to the documentation) a broadcast receiver declared in the manifest does not get killed unless you kill the app manually. I use GCM all the time that starts a service and I never have problems not getting the push message unless there is bad internet or the app was killed manually

Comment: @tyczj: why is it badly implemented ? the BroadcastReceiver is in manifest inside the <application> tag

Answer (score 0):

This is by default by design. Starting from android 3.1 and above any application user removed from the tasks or application manager wont receive any intents broadcasted , based on the following conditions....

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols